# MongoDB aggregate $group and $project with group result

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a collection like this:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5b73d0eb71283a04c45737b3"),
    "rating" : 5,
    "category" : "Camera",
    "topic" : "wifi",
    "version" : 1.0,
    "date" : ISODate("2018-07-11T17:30:00.000-06:30"),
    "jobId" : ObjectId("5b73d089ec6bf63b6df38484"),
    "snippet" : "very good product",
    "sku" : "B0749MNH84",
    "cleanedUp" : true
}
```

I want to aggregate based on a given array of SKUs and topics. My attempt for the same:

```
db.reviews.aggregate(
[
    { $match: { sku: { $in: skus } } },
    { $match: { topic: { $in: topics } } },
    {
            $group: {
                    _id: {
                            topic: '$topic', sku : "$sku"
                        },
                      snippets: {'$addToSet': {snippet: "$snippet"}}

                }
    },
    {
            $project : {
                    _id : false, sku: "$_id.sku", snippets : "$snippets", topic : "$_id.topic"
                }
    }
]
);
```

For a sku `B0749MNH84` and topics `['quality', 'price']`, this gives me the results as :

```
{
  sku : 'B0749MNH84',
  snippets: [Array],
  topic : 'quality'
},
{
  sku : 'B0749MNH84',
  snippets: [Array],
  topic : 'price'
}
```

What I actually want to do, if possible, is to use aggregation pipeline itself to get results in this format (grouped per SKU):

```
    {
      sku : 'B0749MNH84',
      topics: 
         [
           {
                 snippets: [Array],
                 topic : 'quality'
           },
           {
                 snippets: [Array],
                 topic : 'price'
           }
         ]
},
 {
      sku : 'some other SKU',
      topics: 
         [
           {
                 snippets: [Array],
                 topic : 'topic1'
           },
           {
                 snippets: [Array],
                 topic : 'topic2'
           }
         ]
}
```

Of course, I can loop over the results to get the results in this format but I'm wondering if it is possible to do it with aggregation pipeline itself.

Comment: I would try using MongoDB Compass to build the aggregations visually - it's much easier as you see potential results in real time: https://www.mongodb.com/products/compass

Comment: You need to use one more `$group` stage. Something like `db.reviews.aggregate([
  { "$match": { "sku": { "$in": skus }, "topic": { "$in": topics } } },
  { "$group": {
    "_id": {
      "topic": "$topic",
      "sku": "$sku"
    },
    "snippets": { "$addToSet": { "snippet": "$snippet" } }
  }},
  { "$group": {
    "_id": "$_id.sku",
    "topics": { "$push": { "topic": "$_id.topic", "snippet": "$snippet" } }
  }},
  { "$project": {
    "_id": false,
    "sku": "$_id",
    "topics": 1
  }}
])
`

Comment: Thanks you guys. @AnthonyWinzlet thanks man.